# How to use multiple condition in xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have tried with the xpath like `"//HTMLtag[contains(text(),'Yourtext')` and `contains(text(),'Yourtext')]"`, but this case worked for the particular html tag and not for the different tags. how to make it to work for different tags like 
`"//HTMLtag[contains(text(),'Yourtext')]` and

`//HTMLtag[contains(text(),'Yourtext')]"`.

here is the HTML snippet. Have to select admin of group from the below code.

```
<div class="widget">
<div class="widget-body">
    <h3 class="h3b">Admin</h3>
    <h4 class="h4a">Group</h4>
</div>

<div class="widget-body">
    <h3 class="h3b">Admin</h3>
    <h4 class="h4a">Class</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 4):

You haven't explained the requirement very clearly, but perhaps the answer is

```
//div[h3='Admin' and h4='Group']
```

Note that you shouldn't use `contains()` to test whether a node contains some string, unless you specifically want to allow it as a substring: you should use the `'='` operator. And you should avoid using `text()` to fetch the text nodes: this would fail to match, for example,

```
<h3><a href="...">Admin</a></h3>
```

It's nearly always better to match on the string-value of the element, which is what happens when you just select the element node as an operand of `'='`.